# Relations between change of ring and projectivity/injectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

1) If $ P $ is $A$-projective and $ f : A \to B $ is a ring homomorphism then
$ B \otimes P $  is $B$-projective ?

2) If $M$ is $A$-injective and $ f : A \to B $ is a ring homomorphism then
$ Hom_{A}(B; M) $ is $B$-injective ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, since $\hom_B(B \otimes_A P,-) \cong \hom_A(P,-) \circ U$ is a composition of exact functors, where $U : \mathsf{Mod}(B) \to \mathsf{Mod}(A)$ is the forgetful functor.

2) Again yes, since $\hom_B(-,\hom_A(B,M)) \cong \hom_A(-,M) \circ U$.

Comment: But can we use the fact that $Hom(A \otimes B, C ) \simeq Hom (A, Hom (B,C))$ ?

Comment: Can we use that $5$ is a prime number?